# How to fix "autocomplete problem" in visual studio or resharper plugin?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

When I write function with c# in visual studio 2019. I write "vo" after that I have choice "void" when I press "Enter", it's no **space** after word.
The problem just with "void" keyword.
[when I press "void" I have no space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgeXK.png)

I tried to find resolving with no success.
I tried to press "TAB" button, it was same result.

I want to find the way to fix this problem.

Comment: Hey UkraineInTheMembrane - it's no problem with code, it's when I write "private static vo" I press enter to complete "void" type and I have no space after "void" word. It's little problem but I want to solve it.

Comment: it does indeed appear that the autocomplete for void lacks a space after it.

Comment: you could try and create a code snippet to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I understand why this is so - White-space is not inserted because I can write void* in C#. In most other cases, e.g. when I type new a white-space will be inserted automatically.This behavior is not configurable, its not possible to change this.